# Retrieving max from all columns/datatypes in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe (data) that looks like this

```
Col_1    Col_2    Col_3
5        'xyz'    76
10       'abcd'   100
```

I want to print the max value of all columns, regardless if it's numeric or not.  I am using to_frame because I have a lot of comparisons I want to run against the whole dataframe for every column. When I run this:

```
max_value = data.max(numeric_only=None).to_frame().T
```

it only returns:

```
Col_1    Col_3
10       100
```

when ideally it should return:

```
 Col_1   Col_2     Col_3
 10      'xyz'        100
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just run `max` on entire dataframe: `df.max().to_frame().T`

Comment: @Parfait that isn't working unfortunately, it's not picking up the object dtype's.  Just the int columns

Comment: Really? That works perfect for me using your exact data! What version of pandas?: `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: 0.19.2  do you think that could be the issue?  Is it easy to update the Pandas version? Never done it before.  thanks

Comment: @Parfait.  I think that worked.  I updated my Pandas and am seeing text results now.  Thanks!